# is it possible that a stock trades and stamp prices above the bid and the ask price?

Tags: bid-ask, interactive-brokers

I noticed today when looking at the bid and ask of a stock that the bid was 6.02 and the ask was 6.08 and the time and sales were stamping prices of 7.20 despite having bid and and ask unchanged. Is it possible that this occurs or may be a bug of my TWS interactive brokers platform ?

Comment: It could be a fat finger trade.  Can you post the symbol?

Comment: what do you mean by fat finger trade ? symbol was CTRV on pre-market last Friday, very volatile

Comment: A fat finger trade is when  one  places an order of far greater size than intended.Many also use it to describe placing an order far away from the market.  During regular trading hours, this is usually irrelevant. Illiquid stocks during after hours can have huge B/A  spreads. When the quote straddles an even dollar, it's wide, and you're trying to get price improvement, you have to change the $ value as well as the cents value. It's kind of obvious but in a fast market or a moment of carelessness, you can end up buying at the ask or selling at the bid when you had no intention of doing so.

Comment: Given the liquidity of CTRV, a fat finger trade isn't likely to be the culprit since the spread is tight.  I have a feeling that this is bad data but to be sure, go into Time & Sales at the time of the trade to see what the quote and size was.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the full history. These could be all or nothing kind of trades that at times match at different values... However the difference is quite large... So could be a glitch or feed delay

Comment: "what do you mean by fat finger trade?" Wikipedia: [Fat-finger error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-finger_error)

Comment: I have recently bought shares bid was less and had a limit per transection it went through and confirmed number of shares displayed however the following day it all changed the share number was changed to asked price. Can anyone seller do that?
Eg BID 50 I bought 5 shares for 250 (sight confirmed it went through for 5 share pending finalisation during open time) ASKED 300 (but at the time I bought calculations confirmed at a bid price not asked price. Can anyone seller do that? Is it legal? Why accept and confirm only to change at open time?